# Angular 2 dynamic css class issue

Tags: css, angular

I have a table and I want to set a specific css class to the header column when sorting is changed.

```
<th [ngClass]="getSortClass('id')" data-event="sort" (click)="sortBy('id')">
        <span i18n>Id {{getSortClass('id')}}</span>
        <carbon-icon class="bx--table-sort__svg" name="caret--down"></carbon-icon>
      </th>
```

**First time** (full page load) it successfully sets the class value of th:

```
<th _ngcontent-c2="" data-event="sort" class="bx--table-sort--ascending" ng-reflect-ng-class="bx--table-sort--ascending">
            <span _ngcontent-c2="" i18n="">Id bx--table-sort--ascending</span>
            <carbon-icon _ngcontent-c2="" class="" name="caret--down" ng-reflect-bx-class="bx--table-sort__svg" ng-reflect-name="caret--down"><svg class="bx--table-sort__svg" height="5" width="10" viewBox="0 0 10 5"><path d="M10 0L5 5 0 0z"></path></svg></carbon-icon>
          </th>
```

After clicking back and fort on th and sorting is changed, class property is no longer updated but I see with inspect that `ng-reflect-ng-class="bx--table-sort--ascending"` is still updated fine.

```
<th _ngcontent-c2="" data-event="sort" class="" data-previous-value="descending" ng-reflect-ng-class="bx--table-sort--ascending">
            <span _ngcontent-c2="" i18n="">Id bx--table-sort--ascending</span>
            <carbon-icon _ngcontent-c2="" class="" name="caret--down" ng-reflect-bx-class="bx--table-sort__svg" ng-reflect-name="caret--down"><svg class="bx--table-sort__svg" height="5" width="10" viewBox="0 0 10 5"><path d="M10 0L5 5 0 0z"></path></svg></carbon-icon>
          </th>
```

I spent hours but can't figure out. Do you have any idea why this happens?
Do you notice this?

`Id bx--table-sort--ascending`

This is applied **all the time** (Id + getSortClass('id')) so getSortClass returns fine the correct value. But class attribute is not being updated.

Comment: Give us the code for the `getSortClass` and the `sortBy` method and we could maybe help you out easier.